# Is there an analog to matlab's hgtransform in python? It made coding fi

Tags: python, matlab

Is there an analog to matlab's hgtransform in python? It always made create and manipulating geometries so easy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `matplotlib`, you want to use `matplotlib.transforms`.  So, for example, the [Transforms tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html), [Transformations cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Transformations), and the [API documentation](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html)